# git fsck reporting "sha1 mismatch"

Tags: git, sha1, corruption

We have the following problem while running the `git fsck --full --strict` command:

```
error: sha1 mismatch ced885d12a0677f2db9025e1e684c72e67283fcd

error: ced885d12a0677f2db9025e1e684c72e67283fcd: object corrupt or missing
error: sha1 mismatch cf5a1546bd2de5611eaf6136fb5ca02b4e358bec

error: cf5a1546bd2de5611eaf6136fb5ca02b4e358bec: object corrupt or missing
error: sha1 mismatch cf5d9d5723014921370de479c54a73230c86a981

error: cf5d9d5723014921370de479c54a73230c86a981: object corrupt or missing
error: sha1 mismatch cf675ce5bc5eeb5937441c6a02976cf2fa40076b

error: cf675ce5bc5eeb5937441c6a02976cf2fa40076b: object corrupt or missing
error: sha1 mismatch cf7c5156cf127eb7141505946df51b2b57925a50

error: cf7c5156cf127eb7141505946df51b2b57925a50: object corrupt or missing
dangling commit 3468455f0d9d055bbe957744aa10e670469d3912
dangling commit daeec54632203157a70bae93b9d7c3290820c2f9
(more dangling commit messages)
```

(Note: I don't really care about the dangling commit messages.  I focus on the sha1 mismatch problem.)

My interpretation of this message is that git-fsck recomputes the sha1 from the payload but found a sha1 different from the one used to designate the object. The objects are not missing from the repository (I've check w/ git cat-file).

The weird thing is that if I run the command again, I still have the sha1 messages but for different objects:

```
error: sha1 mismatch 1452752024456a509540591c4879b3e3534f457e

error: 1452752024456a509540591c4879b3e3534f457e: object corrupt or missing
error: sha1 mismatch 16e08310d7182e97092d2783c911dbcf66538238

error: 16e08310d7182e97092d2783c911dbcf66538238: object corrupt or missing
dangling commit 3468455f0d9d055bbe957744aa10e670469d3912
```

Note: the repository has not changed between the two runs.

We are running Linux and the current git version is:

```
$git --version
git version 1.7.2.2.170.g5c7f2
```

The errors were there in a previous version (1.6.5.rc2.18.g6d8b).  Those git were built from the sources using gcc 3.4.4.

HOWEVER, when I copy the repository on another host, `git fsck` reports no problem at all. The git version there is 1.7.2.1 (provided by Fedora).

I've made the following observations:

1. The objects having invalid sha1 are often in the same range (in the first example, the sha1s begin with ce or cf) and the errors are triggered within a small period during the fsck run.  I believe git-fsck does an ordered scan (or maybe objects are sorted within the pack).
2. Those objects are relatively big blobs (>900k)
3. We've run a 15-minute complete memtest pass for possible hardware memory failure. We haven't found any problem.  There is no other strange behavior observed on this server which also perform many other non-git tasks.
4. `git gc` is not complaining

Hypotheses so far:

1. This problem is caused by an improper build of git (library version? compiler?)
2. Our memtest failed to find a real memory problem.
3. There is a subtle bug in git-fsck sha1 calculation that occurs randomly (or more precisely within certain short time windows) for large blobs.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Seeing as you are using a non-stable version of git, your best place to ask is likely going to be a Git list or #git on FreeNode IRC. I'd check there to start since it could be a bug in Git, or not, but with a development build, it's best to check.

Comment: I suspected the non-stable development build also.  But strange thing is that both development versions (1.6.5.rc2.18 and 1.7.2.2.170) exhibit the same problem.  I've tried to build a development version on another host, and I run fsck without problem.  Next step was to copy the executable on run it on another host.  No problem also.  So, It seems to be related with the server itself which is running Linux Centos 4.2 on a dual Intel Pentium D@3GHz.  Maybe it's due to some old libraries lying around on Centos.  Is there such a thing as system requirements for Git?

Comment: Perhaps you are getting getting random corruption reading from disk.  That can be caused by many things, often (but not always) hardware.  If hardware, things other than memory can cause it.  Try, for example, to copy your .git directory using `cp -ar` and then `diff -r` the copy with the original.  If they come up different, git is off the hook.

Comment: @Wayne I haven't test that yet.  Let me try....

Comment: @Wayne: tried twice, no diff detected.  If it was the disk, I would expected some sort of I/O error.  But then again, maybe the copy and the diff was too fast to let a an error slip in.  Note: the (bare) repository is 2.9G.  Thanks for your idea!

Comment: @gawi - Oh well.  Sometimes you're the windshield, sometimes you're the fly.

Comment: Smells like faulty RAM if you ask me... I would do a more thorough memory test... Or of you only have a few memory modules in your box, just remove them one by one and see if the problem persists... You mention a 15-minute memory test run but that might not be enough... Use something like memtest86 and let it run through all your memory with a good few patterns...

Comment: @Lasse We've moved our git repo to another host.  Since, the problem disappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must have been some sort of hardware problem.